# unusual No suitable driver found for jdbc://localhost:1527/society

Tags: java, database

previously i using this code to connect my database there is non error occur.

but comes to this DA files, its unable to connect to database.

i had go through most of the post but some of it i don't understand.[i'm just new to java]

i had try to use jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/societydb;create=true

but the same error occur again.

here's the code and <<< is the line the error point to.

```
private String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/societydb";

private String user = "nbuser";
private String password = "nbuser";
private String tableName = "MEMBER";
private void createConnection() {
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
        System.out.println("*** Successfully established the connection to database. ***");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
public ArrayList<Member> getMember() {
    ArrayList<Member> memArray = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);//<<< error pointing to here
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();            
        while (rs.next()){
        Member m = new Member(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getInt(9), rs.getString(10), rs.getString(11));
        memArray.add(m);}
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return memArray;
}
```

Comment: It is not able to find the driver class file. Have you added the required driver jar file in the class path? I don't see any class.forname statement so are you using Java 7?

Comment: i'm not understand about class.forname statement?
can explain on how to get it?

Comment: You need to explicitly load your driver class using Class.forName() call. Eg. for mysql you do Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") and add mysql connector jar file in the class path. Look for appropriate driver class for your derby db. Reason I specified Java 7 is that from java 7 onwards this is done automatically(you simply need to add jar file to the classpath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) the drivers you need are `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` and `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`.

Also it clearly states

```
Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are automatically loaded.(However,
 you must manually load any drivers prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)
```

Note : JDBC 4.0 comes as a default package from Java 7 onwards.

As for your problem search for the classes mentioned above in your class path(`Ctrl + N in Intellij Idea or Ctrl + R in Eclipse`). If these classes are not present google them, download and add the jar files to your class path.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these external jars:

- `derby.jar`
- `derbyclient.jar`

How to do it:

1. right click your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries
2. click 'Add external jar'
3. go to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\db\lib
4. add the `derby.jar` and `derbyclient.jar`